# Turning Ubuntu Server into a Typewriter

Tags: server, vim

I'm attempting to set up a partition on my laptop that, when I boot into it, functions like a typewriter - straight into vim with no other functionality.

I have a partition with ubuntu server installed, and vim, and everything, but it's quite what I was hoping for. For starters, it's just ugly - the font DPI is really low, and color schemes in don't look particularly good (I haven't been able to figure out how to configure it to have colors, yet). I also find myself wanting basic mouse support.

Any suggestions for making Ubuntu Server a bit more workable for this? Is there I terminal emulator I can install without gnome that'll make me happy, or something more like gvim? Or should I give up and just install a full desktop environment?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not terribly experienced with this, so I'm not sure what the rough edges are, but [fbterm](https://code.google.com/p/fbterm/) works for me on the rare occasion I don't boot into X. It comes with fairly basic [gpm](http://www.nico.schottelius.org/software/gpm/)-like mouse support, meaning you can select and paste text, but I haven't succeeded in making Vim read the mouse like it would in an xterm.

Basically you use a framebuffer driver for your video adapter; see [this U&L question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33596/no-framebuffer-device-how-to-enable-it). Then install fbterm and run it; it is available in Ubuntu and is basically an improved console terminal with 256-color support.

It works best when it has unfettered read/write access to /dev/fb0, so make sure your user is in the group `video`; and its keyboard support also works best with the `SYS_TTY_CONFIG` capability, which means you have to run `sudo setcap 'cap_sys_tty_config+ep' /usr/bin/fbterm`. I'm guessing this capability goes away if the fbterm binary is replaced; hopefully someone can suggest a way around this. You could instead run it as root; the program's man page claims it drops root privileges soon after launching.

Make sure to run Vim using `TERM=fbterm` so Vim doesn't get confused (fbterm uses 256-color codes that differ from xterm's). You can then use 256-color themes, or even GUI themes if you use something like [CSApprox](https://github.com/godlygeek/csapprox).